# Merge references of 2 records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a situation where I have a table, say `TableA`, whose `id` is used as a foreign key in several other tables `TableB`, `TableC`, `TableD` etc. There are entries in TableA with ids `1` and `2` that I have to merge. The problem is that each entry may or may not be referenced in any of the other tables. Is it possible to update all the references of `2` to `1` without having to loop through each referencing table using

```
Update Table{X} set TableA_id=1 WHERE TableA_id=2
```

Comment: Why is doing four update queries such an issue?

Comment: `TableA` is sort of the base table in my database. There are way more than four references.

Comment: Is the issue the number of tables or the number of pairs like (2-->1)?

Comment: It's the tables. The entries to be merged will be identified manually.

Comment: . . If you use consistent naming conventions, you can use `information_schema.columns` to find the tables.

Comment: Sounds like you need an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to write some code like this?

```
UPDATE destination
    set destination.id = [new value]
FROM [tableB] destination
INNER JOIN [tableA] foreignkeytable
ON destination.id = foreignkeytable.id
```

Maybe I'm just not fully understanding the request. Hope this helps.